# Search Crawl Error - CannotConnectException

Tags: enterprise-search, crawl

We are crawling an OData Content Source in SP 2013, and we are getting partial succuess of incremental crawl. The unsuccessful crawls are showing following error:

> Error while crawling LOB contents. ( Error caused by exception:
>   Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.CannotConnectException Unable to
>   connect to the remote server; SearchID =
>   3BD4AFA6-BEBB-4E6E-BE3B-A220EC42BB8F )

Anyone has any idea of what could be going on?

I've set the timeout Search settings to following, but didn't help.
`Time-out (seconds) 500, 500`

Comment: Anybody has any pointers of how to resolve this ? I'm really hoping someone can guide.